# Making Python guess a file Name

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

I have the following function:

```
unpack_binaryfunction('third-party/jdk-6u29-linux-i586.bin' , ('/home/user/%s/third-party' % installdir), 'jdk1.6.0_29')
```

Which uses os.sys to execute a java deployment. The line, combined with the function (Which is unimportant, it just calls some linux statements) works perfectly.

However, this only works if in the 'third-party' folder is specificaly that version of the jdk.
Therefore I need a code that will look at the files in the 'third-party' folder and find one that starts with 'jdk' and fill out the rest of the filename itself.

I am absolutely stuck. Are there any functions or libraries that can help with file searching etc?

To clarify: I need the code to not include the entire: jdk-6u29-linux-i586.bin but to use the jdk-xxxx... that will be in the third-party folder.

Comment: Take a look at the `glob` module .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can easily be done using the [glob](https://docs.python.org/library/glob.html) module, and then a bit a string parsing to extract the version.

```
import glob
import os.path

for path in glob.glob('third-party/jdk-*'):
    parent, name = os.path.split(path) # "third-party", "jdk-6u29-linux-i586.bin"
    version, update = name.split('-')[1].split('u') # ("6", "29")
    unpack_binaryfunction(path, ('/home/user/%s/third-party' % installdir), 'jdk1.{}.0_{}'.format(version, update))
```